# On mouse hover on NSButton Change Cursor (for OSX)

Tags: swift, macos, cursor, nsbutton, nscursor

I made  a subclass of NSButton

```
class Button: NSButton {
        var cursor = NSCursor()
       override func resetCursorRects() {
           
           super.resetCursorRects()
           addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: .pointingHand)
       }
   }
```

on my VC class i have added

```
let tempBtn = Button()
```

to call subclass but still no use. What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    class Button: NSButton {
        override func resetCursorRects() {
            super.resetCursorRects()
            addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: .pointingHand)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = Button(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working but my buttons are not programatically created , they created using interface builder . How to do then ?